# Curious, Inquisitive, Socratic badges

Tags: support, badges

I've suddenly earned several *Curious*, *Inquisitive*, and *Socratic* badges.
I'm curious: Are these newly created badges?

Comment: Me too. And I Was going to post a question on meta with the same pun on curious :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that all of these ~2000 badges on the site have been awarded 4 hours ago, it would appear so.

Some explanation: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges), https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262301/badges-for-habitually-asking-well-received-questions.

Comment: Not that badges question are so important, but it seems to me that while these badges might be a good idea, the conditions of their attribution are way too lenient for our site. So basically, if you have five question (asked on different days) with a +1 score, and 4 questions with a -1 score, you get a badge ! That's weird.

Comment: And I thought perhaps I was uniquely identified as *Curious* etc.!

Comment: @Joseph: But isn't Curious George curious as well? :-)

Comment: I was quite tickled to receive my first curious badge, given my avatar :)

Comment: I find the subtle sense of humour behind some of the badges quite amusing; when I was awarded the tumble weed badge, that made my day. I hope, that that kind of twinkle in the eye will not be given up.